# Give a visitor user contribute access in a document library folder

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions

I am facing problem in giving a visitor user permission as "Contribute" on a particular folder inside a document library. In my scenario the user is added in the top site collection inside the visitor group to have read access to all the sub sites, but for one sub site's document library I have a sub folder on which I want to give the user contribute access. I went to that particular library and then that folder selected manage permission and then given the user permission as contribute (by breaking inheritance of permission). Now when I login with the users credential on the document library folder I cannot see the "Add New Item" link, whereas I can edit and delete the previously added files. Can anyone help me in this? What step am I missing?

Comment: Are you on sharepoint 2010 or 2007 ?

Comment: Hi Moss Farmer, I as asking in 2010 context.

Comment: Is this add new item link disabled in the ribbon as well..

Comment: Not even getting the ribbon for that user.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that you have given contribute permission level to the user at the exact folder , then go to the top site collection settings and go to the edit permission level page for contribute and see it the Edit Items and Add Items rights are checked. Alternatively, give the user Design level access temporarily on the folder and see if you are getting the add item option or not.

Comment: Yup I have again cross checked that the user is having contribute rights on the specific folder and as you mentioned I also tried giving him (contribute + design) permissions on that folder but still the user is not able to get the add items link for that folder. On top site collection I found that contribute Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents.

Comment: can anyone help me on this ??

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Sharepoint 2010, navigate to teh library, open library permissions and click "Check permissions" for that user. That should confirm they have contribute access.

If they still cannot add a document, check the contribute permission level has not been customised (eg removed the Add level).

Answer (score 1):

Give the user higher permissions. Try "DESIGN" or higher. Since you are breaking inheritance, this user will only have access to this particular library.

If you don't feel comfortable granting higher permissions.
The users should still be able to add new documents by navigating to the ribbon and trying to add a document from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just stop inheriting permissions for that particular folder. This will enable the option to grant privileges. There you can add more users and assign them permissions.

I tested this in SharePoint 2013. I hope the same thing works if you are using SharePoint 2010. I hope it helps.

Comment: The OP has already done that, it is written in the question..